# How to display events in android calender View

Tags: android, event-handling, calendarview

I Am working on an android application to display Day Events in calendar. Can anyone guide me how can I add events in calendar view to display?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Caldroid Git Repository](https://github.com/roomorama/Caldroid).

It will much easier to add event, display calendar etc.
You can find complete description about how to use it on there page.

Comment: Hi Shubham,                                                                                              Can we achive this from default android calendar.                                        Thanks